# what is the difference between method wrapper and slot wrapper?

Tags: python, methods, wrapper, slot

1) `True.__init__` gives

```
`<method-wrapper '__init__' of bool object at 0x9efaa0>`
```

2) `int.__init__` gives

```
`<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>`
```

what is the difference?

Comment: Note: `int` is a type, `True` is an *object* of the `bool` type`.

Comment: So `bool.__init__` gives us a `<slot wrapper>` as well.